# python - beautifulsoup find_all() resulting invalid date

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

my code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.traveloka.com/hotel/detail?spec=22-9-2016.24-9-2016.2.1.HOTEL.3000010016588.&nc=1474427752464")

data = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
ratingdates = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "reviewDate"})

for i in range(0,10):
    print(ratingdates[i].get_text())
```

Those code will print "Invalid date". How to get the date?

Additional note:

It seems the solution is using selenium or spynner but I don't know how to use it. Moreover I can't install spynner, it always stuck on installing lxml

Comment: The dates are generated through an ajax request, the data is posted to https://api.traveloka.com/v1/hotel/hotelReviewAggregate, it is possible to replicate it but non-trivial.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham would you mind checking my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703021/python-requests-fetch-data-from-api-based-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple if you use Selenium. Here's a basic example with some explanation:

To install selenium run `pip install selenium`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

# set webdriver's browser to Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox() 

#load page in browser
driver.get(
    "https://www.traveloka.com/hotel/detail?spec=22-9-2016.24-9-2016.2.1.HOTEL.3000010016588.&nc=1474427752464")

#Wait 5 seconds after page load so dates are loaded
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
#get page's source
data = driver.page_source

#rest is pretty much the same
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
ratingdates = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "reviewDate"})

#I changed this bit to always print all dates without range issues
for i in ratingdates:
    print(i.get_text())
```

For more on using Selenium take a look at the docs here - http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

If you don't want to get Firefox popping up every time you run the script, you could use `PhantomJS` - a lightweight headerless browser. After [downloading](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) and setting it up you can just change `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` to `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()` in the example above.

Comment: I see, it needs a browser, can I do it without a browser?

Comment: You need something to execute the `js` in page and load the content you want. So you need a browser. There is however an option to do it without opening a new window every time. It's called `PhantomJS` and I've added a bit on it at the end of my answer.